# Git delete file from specific commit

Tags: laravel, git, branch, local, commit

I have to delete a file from previous commmit, I have delete that file from last commit and master branch but that file still showing from different commit

```
 https://github.com/username/repo/blob/ccf60c8e811d911565e5f88e454dd85e45d89d1e/.env
```

but i have deleted `.env` file from master branch.

i have tried below command in local -

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .env' -- --all
```

output was below listed -

```
 Rewrite 83586a63ecb950c5262c851dbbfd521ef5ec8a65 (95/97) (4 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/feature/dependencies' is unchanged
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/mff1' is unchanged
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/mff1' is unchanged
 WARNING: Ref 'refs/stash' is unchanged
```

after that `.env` file still showing on that link -

```
 https://github.com/username/repo/blob/ccf60c8e811d911565e5f88e454dd85e45d89d1e/.env
```

2nd try-

than i used

```
 git obliterate .env
```

its rewrite all commit but still could not delete `.env` file from repo.

Please guide me how to delete that file?

thanks...

Comment: Did this file land on master through a pull request ? github also keeps references + history of commits mentioned in pull requests.

Comment: No! i have deleted this file from master branch, and do not exist in any pull requests.

Comment: `git filter-branch` rewrites the history by creating new objects and moving refs from the old objects to the new ones. The original objects are still there. If the objects are still referred to by some ref, they last forever. Even if they are unreachable from any refs, they stay for quite a while until `git gc` wipes them out. Not sure how Github does `git gc`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `git` will not delete unreferenced blobs straight away ; you need to trigger a garbage collection (`git gc`) on the target copy of the repo.

(I'm searching the github docs to see how you can trigger this on a repo, it would be an action available to a repo's administrator ; other servers (like gitlab) call it "housekeeping"

[edit] couldn't find  it at a quick glance, contact github's tech support

a question you can ask is : "can you please run a `git gc` on my repo ?"
)

---

**Regardless of the above :**
if any secrets have been pushed to that repo, these secrets have been *published*.

You should revoke those secrets and create new ones (e.g : change passwords, generate new keys, etc ...).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking this too to ask git support team.

Answer (score 2):

You literally cannot *remove* commits.  You can only *add* commits.

Suppose that you have an existing Git repository that has 10 commits in it (each of the ten commits has a big ugly hash ID).  The last five of the ten commits have a file named `bad` in them.  To simplify talking about the repository, let's suppose that these ten commits are found by a single main branch (named `master` or `main` or whatever), with no other branch names.

If you use `git filter-branch` to "remove" the bad file named `bad`, what you get is a repository with *fifteen* commits.  Ten of the fifteen commits lack the file named `bad`, and five of the fifteen commits *have* the filed named `bad` in them.  These are the same five commits from before!  All we did was add five new-and-improved commits; the bad commits remain.

The commits that you will find by starting from the *last* commit in the main branch (whatever it is named) and working backwards will be the ten *good* commits.  The five *bad* commits will be hard to find: the only way to find them will be by using the raw hash IDs of any of these five bad commits, e.g., by having saved the hash IDs earlier.  Using a GitHub URL that has the raw hash ID in it counts as using the hash ID: you *will* find the commit this way.

You can now push the updated commits (with `--force`) to GitHub, but this will merely add the five *good* commits to the repository over on GitHub.  That repository will now have all fifteen commits.

This is what you are doing right now.  "Deleting" the bad commits doesn't actually *delete* anything.  Eventually, those commits, if un-find-able, will drop away; or, you can have GitHub support remove them sooner.  But anyone who saved the raw hash ID will be able to get the file back until GitHub eventually removes the commits, if they ever do.

Comment: You explained me much, that didn't think of that, its really help me. thanks